# Need to use a loop or vectorization to create multiple numbered variables while referencing numbered variables

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame called `DF`. `DF` contains around 10,019 variables; 10,000 of them are structured like `z_1` to `z_10000`.

For each of the 10000 `z_ variables` I need to create a new variable, as well as reference the relevant `z_i`. I currently have something like the following which isn't working for me.

```
for (i=1:10000){
DF$newvar_[i] <- pnorm(qnorm(DF$calc1/1-DF$x*DF$z_[i]))
}
```

I appreciate there's usually a requirement for data but hopefully you can see that the actual calculation is the simple part, what is the major issue is getting the code to output a new variable for each of the 10,000 `z_` variables, naming each according to the same number. That is, for `DF$z_1` I want to construct the variable `DF$newvar_1`, for `DF$z_2` I want to construct `DF$newvar_2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
for (i in 1:10000){
DF[paste('newvar_',i, sep="_")] <- pnorm(qnorm(DF$calc1/1-DF$x*DF[paste('z',i, sep="_")])))
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Ravi, when I tested this it came back with error 'Non numeric argument to mathematical function'. I am certain that all of me variables are numerical

Comment: @JohnM Can you do a quick check of data type of the variables, by ``str`` ? You can have this code to convert column into numeric type ``cols.num <- c("a","b")
DF[cols.num] <- sapply(DF[cols.num],as.numeric)`` and re-run the code again

Comment: Hi Ravi; I checked using class  () and all are numeric

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like below?

```
df <- data.frame()
v <- c()
for (i in 1:10000) {
  v <- c(v,sprintf("newvar_%d",i))
  cbind(df,data.frame(pnorm(qnorm(DF$calc1/1-DF$x*eval(parse(text = sprintf("DF$z_%d",i)))))))
}
DF <- cbind(DF, setNames(df,v))
```

Comment: that seemed to work but sent each of the 10,000 created variables to the Global environment rather than gathering them into a single dataframe. Do you have any idea how I can pull them together into a single dataframe? Tell me it isn't as simple as adding a dataframe <- to the beginning of the code?

Comment: @JohnM I updated my code so you can try if it works as you expect